# Есть альтернатива size(), только для массивов?

Tags: c++, массивы

```
void array_print(vector<int> & arr)
{
for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i) cout<<i<<" Ячейка массива:"<<arr[i]<<endl;
}

void array_print(int arr[])
{
for (int i = 0; i < /*arr.size()*/; ++i) cout<<i<<" Ячейка массива:"<<arr[i]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: функция из стандартной библиотеки [std::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size).

Comment: Есть, но только для объектов типа "массив". У вас же функции в `array_print` параметр `arr` является указателем на элемент массива. Узнать размер массива по указателю на его элемент невозможно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В функции `array_print` параметр `arr` является указателем на элемент массива. Узнать размер массива по указателю на его элемент невозможно.

В ситуации, когда размер массива не фиксирован на стадии компиляции, у вас есть только один вариант - передавать размер массива извне вручную

```
void array_print(int arr[], int n)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) cout<<i<<" Ячейка массива:"<<arr[i]<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Есть шаблонная.

```
template<class T, size_t N>
size_t length(T(&)[N])
{
    return N;
}

int main()
{
    int a[10];
    cout << length(a) << endl;
}
```

Но учтите, что фокус типа

```
int * a = new int[20];
cout << length(a) << endl;
```

не пройдет.

Как не пройдет и

```
void func(int a[])
{
    cout << length(a) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Мне нужно использовать значение length() в функции

Comment: Передавайте его в функцию отдельным параметром...